# Azure blob trigger not firing when files being added to the blob

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

I am trying to implement azure blob trigger for my ADLS2 storage

Here is the simple trigger

```
public class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public void Run([BlobTrigger("sample/my-directory/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    }
}
```

But when I upload new files into the container **sample**/my-directory it is not triggering my blob trigger.

But again, As in the below screenshot, my connection string is valid. I am able to connect to the storage using the same connectionstring from StorageExplorer and also below dependencies shows its connecting fine.

Here is my local.settings.json file as well

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",,
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"

  }
}
```

Please share your thoughts what did I missed or my approach is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see that on your Connected Services the `Azure Storage: aplledossdevuksstd` 's Connection String name is replaced with Connection String value but need to provide just a sample connection string name. Its value is automatically will be stored in `Secrets.json`.

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, you can add your connection string in local.settings.json and add the connection string name in `Function1.cs`

### local.settings.json

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<YOUR CONNECTION STRING>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

### Function1.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp3
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("samples/dir1/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]